# Why might average free memory slots dramatically increase after upgrading to Ruby 2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memory

I recently upgraded a Rails app to use Ruby 2.6.1 and saw that average free memory slots ([as measured by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/language-runtime-metrics-ruby#free-memory-slots)) dramatically increased.

I cannot find any related issues and curious if anyone has seen this or has an idea for why it is happening.  See the two graphs below for more info -- The first is the overall trend after the deploy with Ruby 2.6.1 and the second is a more detailed view that shows a recurring pattern for memory slots decreasing.

[image: trend after updating to Ruby 2.6.1]

[image: Detailed view]

**UPDATE**

To give some more context, I've added graphs showing memory usage and heap objects pre and post Ruby 2.6.1 upgrade.  Both are very similar, with the exception that after the 2.6.1 upgrade more objects are being freed.  Everything is functioning well, but I am still interested in why this might be happening.

If it is an intended memory optimization, I wonder if [Heroku's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/language-runtime-metrics-ruby#heap-object-count)/[@nateberkopec's](https://www.speedshop.co/2017/03/09/a-guide-to-gc-stat.html) assertion that "Large numbers of free slots (for example more than 300,000) indicates that there is a controller action that is allocating large numbers of objects and freeing them," needs to be amended for Ruby 2.6.

Memory usage:
[image: memory usage]

Heap objects:
[image: heap objects]

Comment: with or without jit?

Comment: @Anthony without jit

Comment: Can you easily compare to other Ruby versions?

Comment: @tadman I'm going to try to compare locally, but want to avoid downgrading prod at least initially.  Hoping someone has had the same issue 

Comment: If this is a problem where memory consumption keeps going up it could be a quirk of the garbage collector and an application specific problem. The first thing to check is if the same code on a different Ruby behaves differently than different code on the same Ruby.

Comment: @tadman the only thing that changed in deploy where the memory slots starting spiking is the ruby version from 2.5.3 to 2.6.1.  The memory does not continue to grow -- the free slots spike on a ten minute interval then linearly decrease for 10 minutes (second graph).

Comment: Ruby 2.6.x onward has made changes designed to improve memory and performance. Besides the chart you're looking at on Heroku, does your app seem to be performing any differently?  But unless you have a wide range of benchmarks and performance metrics from before the upgrade to compare, you could be shooting in the dark.  Not sure if this is relevant, but I was able to improve an app's memory performance recently with jemalloc see
https://engineering.appfolio.com/appfolio-engineering/2018/2/1/benchmarking-rubys-heap-malloc-tcmalloc-jemalloc

Comment: Thanks for the resource @lacostenycoder! Everything seems to be performing fine, just interested in figuring out why it's happening...

Comment: Just noticed this with our app, did you ever find an answer to this question @weilandia ?

Comment: Hey Ryan, I never did figure out what exactly is happening.

Comment: When I upgraded my app from 2.6.5 to 2.7 yesterday, the spikes in free memory slots completely went away. In addition, the freed heap objects now match the alloc numbers, whereas before the freed # was close to 0. Using jemalloc before/after as well

Answer (score 0):

I cannot exactly say without looking at your code.

However, do note that **garbage collection changed** in ruby 2.6

I have not been able to find much information about it, but I noticed it changed because temp files were being deleted at a different time than before the upgrade. I tested this a bunch and it seems the triggers/conditions that cause garbage collection changed.

Here are some links I have been looking at, but as mentioned there is not enough information there:
https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2018/12/25/ruby-2-6-0-released/

https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html